# Работа с авторизованными пользователями

Tags: php, регистрация, mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня следующий вопрос, как можно привязать пользователей сайта, для публикациями ими сообщений на пример в гостевую книгу. После того как пользователь авторизировался на сайте, и ему захотелось от своего имени оставить сообщение в гостевую книгу. Как это сделать на сайте, не имею понятий, может и имею. Но пока не понимаю как привязать пользователей к форме.

Comment: поправьте теги вопроса, привяжите вопрос хотя бы к одному языку программирования, или CMS.

Comment: поправил на php и mysql

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в том, как запомнить авторизованного пользователя, то во время авторизации, после проверки логина/пароля, используйте что-то вроде:

```
$_SESSION['mysite_uid'] = $id); //Устанавливаем переменную сессии mysite_uid в значение идентификатора пользователя, из БД.
```

При каждой загрузке страницы проверяете, существуют ли  сессия и переменная с таким названием:

```
session_start(); // Проверяем наличие сессии. Если нет, она создаётся
if(isset($_SESSION['mysite_uid'])) { //Пользователь авторизован
  //Забираем из базы нужную информацию, для пользователя с id равным $_SESSION['mysite_uid'].
}
else {
 //Нет авторизации, предлагаем войти или зарегистрироваться.
}
```

При выходе пользователя с сайта:

```
unset($_SESSION["mysite_uid"]); //Удаляем id.
session_destroy(); //Убиваем сессию.
```

Comment: выставлять uid в куках ??

Comment: @eicto, не, ну пишите туда сессию, но нафиг? Для гостевой книги? Я не понимаю, на черта там авторизация?

Comment: ну это дело ТС зачем авторизация, а вот uid в куку... вы вообще часто пишите авторизацию таким образом ?

Comment: @eicto, нет, использую сессии, или хеши. Но мне показалось, что в данном случае хватит и этого. Впрочем, уже переписал.

Comment: Мне нужна подсказка, в следующем: есть форма http://proet.ru/2214.jpg.  Где логан пользователя "(красным цветом) и которую информацию, нужно мне подсказать" какой код вписать, что в итоге выходило: пользователь XXX (из базы) написал FFF сообщение.

Comment: Тут ясно что без COOKIE. Так как пользователь уже на сайте, а вот имя пока он пишет сам при заполнение полей. А мне хотелось что программа сама его записывала при отправки данных на сайт. Когда данные должны подставляться в таблицу БД и отображаться на сайте.

Comment: чет я не нашел там никакой красной тачки.

Comment: Значит смотрели не внимательно. Там крастным надпись" логин пользователя"

Answer (score 0):

Учите английский и в [любой](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20mysql%20registration%20tutorial&oq=php%20mysql%20registration%20tutorial) tutorial(учебник).
Ваш вопрос слишком общий, существует очень много вариантов его решения. Научитесь сначала задавать вопросы в Google.

Comment: мне нужна подсказка, к следующей информации:
Когда пользователь авторизируется на сайте, и он захочет оставить сообщение в гостевой. Как заносить данные его в форуму.

Comment: Чтобы потов когда форма обновится в базе и уйдет на сайт. Пользователь смогу видить на сайте свое имя и свое сообщение.

Comment: учитывая ваши комментарии, вы не силно разбираетесь в вопросе. Именно поэтому, советую поучиться. А вы ждете от людей готового решения. Если вам нужно готовое решение, ищите его в интернетах

Comment: Мне нужна подсказка, в следующем: есть форма http://proet.ru/2214.jpg.  Где логан пользователя "(красным цветом) и которую информацию, нужно мне подсказать" какой код вписать, что в итоге выходило: пользователь XXX (из базы) написал FFF сообщение.

Comment: Тут ясно что без COOKIE.  Так как пользователь уже на сайте, а вот имя пока он пишет сам при заполнение полей. А мне хотелось что программа сама его записывала при отправки данных на сайт. Когда данные должны подставляться в таблицу БД и отображаться на сайте.